# Java Garbage Collection of referenced objects

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm getting some strange behaviour in one of my apps, objects (member variables) against one of my classes are being nullified before the lifecycle of my class has completed, obviously resulting in null pointer exceptions.

It seems to happen after a period of time (presumably due to high memory usage or memory leak).

I know that the GC shouldn't collect any objects which are referenced. But, in a low memory scenario, does this rule still apply and will referenced objects be put up for GC?

I've knocked up a sample to demonstrate my code pattern:

Thanks in advance.

```
public class WebRequest implements Runnable {

    private WebRequest _Request;

    public WebRequest(WebRequest request)
    {
        _Request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        DoSomething1();
        DoSomething2();
    }

    private void DoSomething1()
    {
        String s = _Request.getAttribute(); //Works
        //Do something else, few hundred milliseconds
    }

    private void DoSomething2()
    {
        String s = _Request.getAttribute(); //Results in NullPointerException
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the field really `final`? Is there any reflection involved? Where and how does `WebRequest` get used.

Comment: Apologies, the field which exhibits the issue isn't final (updated). WebRequest wraps a HTTP request which is processed via ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: I suggest you're clearing this field yourself somewhere. GC doesn't nullify fields.

Comment: @EJP, I have double checked that following your initial comment, the field in question is not assigned to following its instantiation in the constructor. Thanks for confirmation on the GC. I've really got no idea now.

Comment: Are you sure this line of code causes the NPE? Or is it something inside getAttribute()?

Comment: I figured that if getAttribute (returns string) evaluated to null, it would just assign s = null. _Request would need to be null to throw a NPE. Please correct me if I'm wrong though?

Comment: You're correct about that *if* the NPE is really thrown from exactly that line, which was my question, which you haven't answered. I didn't ask about `getAttribute()` returning null, I asked about possible NPEs inside it.

Comment: getAttribute just exposes a private string member variable. So I'd ruled that out tbh

Comment: Getting a more experienced dev to investigate this issue. Will post findings once I know more. Thanks for the help so far.